# segmentation fault with strcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

I am wondering why am I getting segmentation fault in the below code.

```
int main(void)
{
        char str[100]="My name is Vutukuri";
        char *str_old,*str_new;

        str_old=str;
        strcpy(str_new,str_old);

        puts(str_new);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You haven't initialized `*str_new` so it is just copying `str_old` to some random address.
You need to do either this:

```
char str_new[100];
```

or

```
char * str = (char *) malloc(100);
```

You will have to `#include <stdlib.h>` if you haven't already when using the malloc function.

Answer (score 9):

`str_new` is an uninitialized pointer, so you are trying to write to a (quasi)random address.

Answer (score 3):

Because `str_new` doesn't point to valid memory -- it is uninitialized, contains garbage, and likely points into memory that's not even mapped if you're getting a segmentation error. You have to make `str_new` point to a valid block of memory large enough to hold the string of interest -- including the `\0` byte at the end -- before calling `strcpy()`.