# strcpy() giving me Segmentation Fault (core dumped) even with (char*, const char*) inputs

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

this is my very simple code:

```
char thing[256];
char *athing;
strcpy(thing, "Hello, ");
strcpy(athing, "World!");
printf("%s\n%s\n", thing, athing);

return 0;
```

And whenever I run it, it gives me `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`

I use GCC to compile my code

Please Help!

Comment: `char *athing;` has no memory allocation, therefore `strcpy(athing, "World!");` is doomed to failure. You could try `char *athing = malloc(256);` or you could try `char *athing = "World!";` instead of the `strcpy`.

Comment: `char *athing;` ==> `char *athing = malloc(1000); if (!athing) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* ... use athing ... */ free(athing);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this post: [segmentation fault with strcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326586/segmentation-fault-with-strcpy)

The idea is that your pointer athing is not initialized, so it points to a random location in memory, which results in a segfault when you try to access it.